# Vue Refresh page execute multiple axios.post

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

In App.Vue i have this code:

```
<script>
import axios from "axios";
import { baseApiUrl, userInfo } from "@/global";

export default {
  methods: {
    moveToLoginPage() {
      localStorage.removeItem(userInfo);
      this.$store.commit("setToken", null);
      this.$router.push({ path: "/login" });
    },
    async validateToken() {
      const json = localStorage.getItem(userInfo);
      const userData = JSON.parse(json);
      if (!userData) {
        this.moveToLoginPage();
      } else {
        const url = `${baseApiUrl}/auth/validateToken`;
        const resData = await axios.post(url, userData).then(resp => resp.data);
        if (!resData) {
          this.moveToLoginPage();
        }
      }
    }
  },
  created() {
    this.validateToken();
  }
};
</script>
```

After access the system I go to any other page, and give a refresh. When the page is reloaded, this code snippet from Vue.app is executed to validate the token from localStorage. But before I get the response from the server in validateToken() function, other HTTP.GET requests are executed in the page I has refreshed in function mounted(). I would like the validateToken() function to fully execute before the other page's mounted() function is executed.

Comment: It's hard to comprehend what you mean, but maybe try the `beforeCreate()` function, if that's what you mean?

Comment: I tried using the beforeCreate () function, but the behavior is the same.

Comment: Do you mean how to stop requests from other pages to wait till the time validateToken is resolved?

Comment: I would like the validateToken() function code execute completely without any other application code being executed.
My problem is that after the code below is executed the mounted() function of the screen I refreshed is executed. I want to finish executing the validateToken() function first.

```const resData = await axios.post (url, userData) .then (resp => resp.data);```

Comment: Can you post the template part of your App.vue file? I need to see how you are routing to other pages. If there's a router-view in App.vue, you can simply put a v-if condition to load the router only if the data is resolved.

Comment: @Praveen Puglia, I did what you suggested and it worked, thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `async/await` like so:

```
async created(){
    await this.validateToken();
    }
```

This will prevent the create lifecycle hook from completing until the validateToken returns a response

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you have a `router-view` in your App.vue file.
You can keep a flag / variable for your async data and then load the `router-view` only if that data is available.

```html
<template>
  <router-view v-if="data"></router-view>
</template>
```

This way, your inner children aren't even loaded till the time your async data is available.

This answer is just the same comment I made on the question above but for future people to come.